# Convert this SQL  Count statement to LINQ statement

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

How would this SQL statement be with LINQ if I use Count?

```
select count(*) from GoalCard
where GoalCard.Completed_Date is not null
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I would remove the " too localized " votes, beacuse there are peoples that use google to find how count can be used in a LINQ statement.

Comment: People who use google to find out how you can use `count` in linq **are finding A LOT of results already**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
context.GoalCards.Count(gc => gc.Completed_Data != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Count:

```
context.GoalCards.Count(x => x.Completed_Date.HasVale)
```